# How do I find the framerate I am playing my game at?

Tags: framerate

I hear people suggesting I should have at-least 30FPS in the game to have a satisfactory experience, I wonder, how do I enable FPS monitoring in a gameplay?

Comment: Remember that it's meaningless to have 9000 FPS if your monitor is 60 Hz :)

Comment: Forget what others say about your experience, if you enjoy it, so it's a good one period. In addition, the time of the day on the planet and where you are, affects FPS a lot, in special in places where there's a beautiful purple haze.

Answer (score 8):

[Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/) is a Windows program that allows you to monitor the frame rate of any game "utilizing DirectX or OpenGL graphic technology". It also allows you to easily take screenshots and videos of your gameplay. There's a perfectly functional free version, but it only supports 30 second videos, has a small watermark, and screenshots are in the .bmp format.

Comment: F12 changes where the numbers are shown and F9 starts/stops recording. Note while recording it drops your FPS a lot and numbers got red

Comment: Fraps is not ideal since it will also eat into games resources and can cause game to lack. A better option is to activate in-game FPS counter.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to display FPS in game [as explained here.](https://www.howtogeek.com/209710/4-quick-ways-to-see-a-pc-game%E2%80%99s-fps-frames-per-second)

**Best option is to rely on the game itself**. If there is no option, I guess relying on **Steam overlay** or **GeForce Experience** would be better (as they may be already running anyway).

If you are using neither of those, **[Fraps](https://www.fraps.com/)** generally is a solid option. Personally I use **[RivaTuner](https://rivatuner.com/)** server to handle FPS (among other things). It has more options to integrate its statistics, but is way more complex.

Answer (score 1):

Some games can display the current FPS if you enable the right setting. It might even be a console command.

30FPS is still quite low. It would be worth trying higher rates to see what you prefer. Some people prefer really high FPS and low resolution while others are exactly the opposite. It's very subjective and so worth experimenting to see what works for you.

Answer (score 0):

In America's Army it is possible to view the current frame rate by entering
stat fps
into the console. Perhaps this works for other games using the Unreal engine too.

You will notice how your frame rate depends on the current environment. In some areas you will perhaps get 60-70fps (usually inside buildings) while in large outdoor environments it will drop to 25-35fps.

Comment: You can't make assumptions on FPS, for me I'll have near 150 FPS inside, and like 100 outside, but it really depends on the game.

Comment: I wasn't making assumptions, just using an example. Emphasis on the _perhaps_. Denotes Vaibhav's case might be different.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question and talks about different game to boot.